# C++20 modules TS: still need function declaration?

Tags: c++, module, function-declaration, c++20

I hope a quick small question to those who tried C++20 modules

According to TS, should this code compile in C++20?

```
void f1() { f2(); }
void f2() { ... }
```

For example, in C++11 it won't compile, because f1() doesn't "know" about the f2(), f2() must be declared before usage.

But maybe in C++20 this requirement will be eliminated in modules?

If the first code snippet is not compiled, will this one compile

```
void f1() { f2(); }
export void f2() { ... }
```

because f2() will be seen from the BMI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Modules does change many things about name lookup (the latest paper I'm aware of is [P1103R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1103r1.pdf)), Modules will not change the fundamental property of C++ that names must be declared before use (modulo things like dependent unqualified calls - which simply delays the lookup, but it still has to actually happen).

This:

```
void f1() { f2(); }
export void f2() { ... }
```

will still be a compile error if there is no previous declaration of `f2` or it wasn't imported from somewhere. You'll have to write:

```
export void f2() { ... }
void f1() { f2(); }
```